# Samba internal network fileserver (without passwords)

Tags: linux, windows, samba, file-server

I'm trying to setup very simple file server with Samba.

Security is not concern, as server is only accessible from internal network that's why my configuration problem looks like this:

```
[global]
    guest account = dan
    netbios name = FS
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    security = share
    smb ports = 139
[storage2]
    path = /storage2
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

Unfortunaly I keep getting:

```
[2009/12/27 16:54:27, 0] smbd/service.c:make_connection_snum(1012) '/storage2' does not exist or permission denied when connecting to [storage2] Error was Permission denied
```

Though I can do:

```
[root@fs samba]# cd /storage2/
[root@fs storage2]# pwd
/storage2
```

Both samba and system user dan exist

I can't understand what may be wrong with this simple configuration.

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow access by everyone try adding these 2 lines to the share

```
    create mode = 777
    directory mode = 777
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the permissions on the directory itself as well?
Look at the permissions of the directory with

```
ls -la /storage2/
```

Does the user "dan" have enough permissions?